# Starting emulator for AVD avd PANIC: Could not open: avd - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I had been using the android sdk for quite some time in my Ubuntu. Recently, I upgraded it to Ubuntu 13.10. From then on, whenever I try to launch an android virtual device, I get this error :

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Ace2'
PANIC: Could not open: Ace2
```

I tried changing the permissions for the files and folders but still no improvement. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that the AVD was created for a different user, as [this blog post](http://rafeebuet.blogspot.in/2012/05/can-not-start-avd-after-creating.html) suggests. Check your /home/**your-user-name**/.android/avd content as well as /root/.android/avd. In my case, the AVDs I created landed up in root, whereas the IDE tried to find them in my user avd directory. Copying everything to the other AVD directory did the trick.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which was fixed by following the advise on this thread (which was the main issue) but was not sufficient. I had to do more in my case. Please see if the below helps.

First, since I had started eclipse using the command
  "sudo ./eclipse"
the ".android/avd" was created under "/root" rather than under "/usr/myname". This, I corrected by copying ".android/avd" from "root" to "/usr/myname".

However, that still did not fix things. I then had to change permissions in two places as follows 
  cd /usr
  chmod a+r+w+x -R myname         (this to ensure that the folder myname and all subfolders get max access rights).
  cd /usr/local
  chmod a+r+w+x -R adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030

Finally, while starting eclipse again, just type
 ./eclipse     (without sudo).

Bingo. That did it. 
Note: You will see that I have provided max permissions to all subfolders, that is because mine is a learning setup. Depending on your usage, you may need to be careful providing read/write/execute access to all folders under two main directories that contain user data.

Answer (score 1):

even i was facing the same issue , got resolved as of now

If you are using Eclipse IDE then after setting the Environment variable :

> name : ANDROID_SDK_HOME
>
> value : C:\Users\user

this should be the path where your .android is residing in my case : C:\Users\user.android.. but don't add .android in path.

Go to eclipse > windows > preferences > run/debug > string substitution > new
:

> name : user.home
>
> value : C:\Users\user

the same path as in environment variable.

Later close your eclipse then

> run again as admin

.

Answer (score 0):

The AVD location that Android IDE is searching in may be wrong.

The easiest way to check is to create a new AVD with AVD manager and check if the location is the same as 'Ace2' and that it can be run with:

```
emulator -avd <avd-name>
```

If not, shift 'Ace 2' over to the correct location and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The way how I solved this problem.
I examined my HOME directory and found that there's a hidden folder *.android* and it's owner was **root**. I think it happened because I launched eclipse as superuser several times.
Then I simply changed the owner and the group of that folder *.android* (**chown** command) and it helped. I created new AVD and managed to start it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux:
I got this failure, because I started the first time the emulator with root and afterwards I started with sudo or normal user!
Also I tried to start an emulator who didnt exists.

So try to start as root!

Answer (score 0):

I started using Eclipse, and going through the error: 
PANIC:Could not open AVD.
When I created a new AVD in AVD Manager, I saw the path shown there was :
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.android\avd

Taking reference from the above posts, I tried copying avd folder from just mentioned path to :
C:\Users\User_name.android folder and it worked.

I hope this may help you.
Thanks.