# Ubuntu 13.10 Eclipse Creating Android AVD Not Working

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, ubuntu-13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on a 32 bit machine. Downloaded and installed Eclipse Kepler also 32 bit version in addition of JDK and JRE also 32 bit versions.

I downloaded latest Android SDK (API 19) but when I start Eclipse as user (not su) and try to create AVD, I get this error:

> [2014-03-26 21:17:55 - SDK Manager] Error: null

and AVD is not created.

If I start Eclipse as su and attempt the same, I can create AVD but it will never start and I get:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'NEX5'
>
> PANIC: Could not open: NEX5

If I try to add already preset AVD "AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google, I get error:
/home/username/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google.ini (Permission denied)

Please help.  I am also new to Linux, so please provide some explanations.

Comment: same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866033/starting-emulator-for-avd-avd-panic-could-not-open-avd-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Some suggest that `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` will help. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk)

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for your reply, unfortunatelly 1st link did not work, 2nd is for 64bit systems, mine is 32 bit.